# insert a formula with varying parameteres - error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup, vba

I'm quite new in programming and I'm a self-taught in this field (copying lots of code lines from internet, mostly from here!).

I have to insert some calculations in new sheets and, between them, a vlookup formula where in each sheet the table range changes. As I'm a beginner in code writing, when I need to write something new I use to record a macro, then I modify it 'till I reach my goal.

In this case I recorded the formula:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[16]C[-6],R[14]C[-6]:R[19]C[-5],2,TRUE)"
```

and modified it as:

```
Dim n, i As Integer
Dim mCell As Range

n = 7
i = 13726
Set mCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(3 + n + 8, 2)

Cells(4, 15).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(3, 15) & ";" & Range(Cells(3 + n + 8, mCell.Column), Cells(i - 1, n + 1)) & ";2;TRUE)"
```

before to insert it in the main macro. This is a simplified cut of the macro (I fixed the variables, where in the original one they will change for each new workbook).

When I run it I receive an "error 13 - type mismatch".
Looking for answers and doing a lot of "try&error", I checked it again and again and I changed quite a lot of pieces of the formula:

- Cells(4,15) / Range("O4")
- .Formula / .FormulaLocal / .Value
- "=VLOOKUP(" / "=BUSCARV(" --> I'm working with excel in spanish, in the sheet the functions are traslated
- Cells(3,15) and Range(...) / Cells(3,15).Address and Range(...) / Cells(3,15).Address and Range(...).Address
- , / ; --> in the sheet I have to use ";", in VBA is recorded automatically as ","
- TRUE / VERDADERO --> still the spanish point

I've written all the permutations (or combinations? :-P ) and run subsiquently all them (144 variations), always receiving the same error type.

So, probably the problem is elsewhere... what am I missing?
thank you so much!!

Comment: There is no need to use `Integer` over `Long`: [Integers vs Longs 32-bit vs 64-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is **English** oriented, if you are using the **Spanish** version, then first you need to change from `Formula` to `FormulaLocal`. When using in a formula `;` instead of `,` as a delimiter between the Function parameters, you will need to use `FormulaLocal`.

Second, you dim `Dim n, i As Integer` , this means `i As Integer` while `n As Variant`, you need to define `Dim n As Long, i As Long`.

**Code**

```
Cells(4, 15).FormulaLocal = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(3, 15).Address & ";" & Range(Cells(3 + n + 8, mCell.Column), Cells(i - 1, n + 1)).Address & ";2;TRUE)"
```

Comment: OMG thank you!!! I didn't know about the long vs integer issue, however i is used in a counting loop, while n just reads a value in a cell.

Comment: ops, entered "enter" for error... So thank you Shai and thank you @Ralph! a Little more note: I writed wrongly how I changed some pieces of formula, I tried: 'Cells(3,15) and Range(...)' / 'Cells(3,15).Address and Range(...)' / 'Cells(3,15).Address and Range(cells().Address, cells().Address)', so probably was also this point that didn't work.